# SQL Query Creation Error in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My Query:

```
dt = db.ExecuteDataTable("SELECT [Serial],[BookSerial],[AlmariNo],[takno],[KitabNo],
[KolamNo],[CopyNo],[TotalVolium],[Volium],[PartNo],[PageNo],[Price],[BookName],
[BookKnownName],[WriterName],[WriterDOB],[WriterDD],[WriterMazhab],[Songkolok],[Onubadok],
[OnubadokDOB_DD],[OnubadokMazvab],[BookLanguage],[TranslateLanguage],[Bishoy],[Chapter],
[Publisher],[PublishDate],[Publication],[PublishYear],[PublicationPlace],[Editor],[Edition],
[suchi],[Remarks],[BookId] FROM [dbo].[bookInfo] WHERE '" + query + "'");
```

Query value:

```
[BookName]LIKE'%ASPSolution%'or[WriterName]LIKE'%ASPSolution%'or[BookLanguage]LIKE'%ASPSolution%'
```

Error:

> {"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near ''."}

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(query.Length);

for (int index = 0; index < query.Length; index++)
{
    if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(query, index))
    {
        output.Append(query[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query value needs spaces, you can't put tables against conditions like that, put spaces between [BookName] and Like, and in 'or[writer' to ' or [writer...'  etc.. Spaces!

Comment: Why are you using `if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(querry, index))` this will remove spaces.

Comment: I needed to remove spaces between '%ASP Solution%'. "ASP Solution"  i am getting this value from textbox.

Comment: Thank You I ran the string binder in textbox value... it works fine now..

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: I have no idea on parametrized queries. can you suggest me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you use parameterized query it will be better because your current
>   query is open for sql injection.

You need space between the conditions also you don't need to surround the `query` variable with single qoutes as this is also of `string` type.

Change your select like this

```
"SELECT [Serial],[BookSerial],[AlmariNo],[takno],[KitabNo],[KolamNo],[CopyNo],[TotalVolium],[Volium],[PartNo],[PageNo],[Price],[BookName],[BookKnownName],[WriterName],[WriterDOB],[WriterDD],[WriterMazhab],[Songkolok],[Onubadok],[OnubadokDOB_DD],[OnubadokMazvab],[BookLanguage],[TranslateLanguage],[Bishoy],[Chapter],[Publisher],[PublishDate],[Publication],[PublishYear],[PublicationPlace],[Editor],[Edition],[suchi],[Remarks],[BookId] FROM [dbo].[bookInfo] WHERE " + query;
```

And you `query` variable like this

```
[BookName] LIKE '%ASPSolution%' or [WriterName] LIKE '%ASPSolution%' or [BookLanguage] LIKE '%ASPSolution%'
```

Comment: At first i was giving spaces but i needed to remove space between '%ASP Solution% ' . For that i ran a string builder. It removes all the spaces. I am giving my code. Can you help me?

Comment: remove single quotes after WHERE